# Angular lazy loading - specific scenarios

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I have page with route /home

my home component has nested components and nested components have nested components as well.

ex.

`<parent> <child> <childOfChild> </childOfChild> </child> <child></child>  </parent>`

Additionally

> 

is using in 4 more routes as :

`<parent> <childOfChild></childOfChild> </parent>`

I am not very familiar with lazy loading in angular. I watched few guides and i understand basic concepts.how to implement lazy loading in this exmaple?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What final result are you trying to achieve? To generate pages, you should use the following command: `ng g module register --module account --route register`. If you also  want nested navigation (keep parent pages visible in sub-pages) you can just add this component to that route too